# What language can be recommended for text mining/parsing?

Tags: java, r, prolog, nlp, text-mining

I'm doing some text mining in web pages. Currently I'm working with Java, but maybe there is more appropriate languages to do what I want.

Example of some things I want to do:

Determine the char type of a word based on it parts (letter, digit, symbols, etc.) as Alphabetic, Number, Alphanumeric, Symbol, etc.(there is more types).

Discover stop words based on statistics.

Discover some gramatical class (verb, noun, preposition, conjuntion) based on statistics and some logics.

I was thinking about using Prolog and R (I don't know much about these languages), but I don't know if they are good for this or maybe, another language more appropriate.

Which can I use? Good libs for Java are welcome too.

Comment: What do you mean by better?  If you know Java, its going to take you longer to learn another language that the time it might save you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't want a better language, but only know if there is something more focused in the things I want that doing all in Java. I don't studied the languages deeply yet, but I guess that R is more appropriate and/or easy to some statistical analysis from a database than in Java.

Comment: Perl is my go-to text parsing and manipulation language, but I think where you don't know it you may be just as well served to use Java for this particular kind of work. Determining character class, for example, seems to have equal work in both languages.

Comment: I'd use Python first for processing and R for deeper statistics, if Python doesn't give what you need.  I wouldn't bother with Perl and Java, unless other people in your org use them.  Big projects should not be done in Perl.  The tools in Python often exceed the comparable offerings in Java and Perl.  That said, I've done text processing in every language but Python.  I wish I had been using Python for text processing.  :)

Answer (score 4):

python.!
They have a HELL-LOTTA libraries in this area.

but,  i've got no knowledge about prologue and R.. but definitely py is LOT better than java in text mining, and AI stuff...

Comment: If you are going to use python for this, definately look into the NLTK library (http://www.nltk.org). the NLTK Book is also very good.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [Perl](http://www.perl.org). It has a lot of text-processing features, web search and parsing, and a large etc. Take a look at the available modules (>23.000 and [growing](http://search.cpan.org/recent)) at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

Comment: If you are going to use Perl for text mining, you may want to look into the book "Text Mining Application Handbook". All the code samples for that book are in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

I think Apache Solr and Nutch provides you the framework for that and on top of that you can extend it for your requirements.

Java has some basic support, but nothing like the above two products, they are awesome!

Comment: For this type of work in Java, I've heard good things about the LingPipe library. http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/ Though the licensing looks a bit steep to me for non-research use

Comment: I wouldn't particularly go the Nutch way for this scenario, its a bit cumbersome to work with and not much active community. Though it does a good job in downloading tons of websites backed by Hadoop clusters.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) might give you some good APIs for fetching web pages, and traversing over elements in DOM by XPath. I have used it for sometime to perform simple to more complex operations.